# Not able to find method to unpublish component with particular CT

Tags: 2013

I am searching for a method in Tom.Net or core service to unpublish a component with a particular Component Template or a method which can unpublish the CT with all component created with particular schema. I was not able to figure out any method for unpublishing in Tom.Net which can work for a component template(if I use component Ids) or a schema(If I use component template). Please suggest, if anyone have used this type of methods earlier.

Little background about issue:

Because of some issue in our custom resolver implementation we have component published with wrong CT. Now we have to unpublish those components with wrong CT. We can't unpublish component with all CTs as this is a live environment.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, instead of un-publishing component, un-publish component template.

Un-publishing of component template will take care of the unpublishing components published using that template.

**Update**

If component template is referring to more than one schema and you want to unpublish components only related to one schema then update custom resolver to perform that validation and remove other components while unpublishing component template.

Comment: Hi Hiren, I could unpublish the CT but I was not able to find unpublish method in API which can work for a particular schema.
I can't unpublish the CT for all the components, as it is a live site.

Comment: Updated my answer based your requirement.

Comment: Hi Hiren, This could be a solution, so +1 for this solution. But changes in custom resolver is global and I can't pass a CT Id and Schema ID from Tridion to filter in custom resolver until I hardcode it in the code.
I wanted to create a custom page which I can run whenever I need and pass a component template ID and Schema ID.

Comment: You may have to get all the components first, then unpublish them one by one. Not 100% sure of CoreService syntax, but you can definitely tell Tridion to unpublish a given Component Template + Component + Target combination.